# How to set the max execution time of script in php when the server is in safe mode?

Tags: php, execution-time

I want to upload and download files to a server. As the server is in safe mode it is not allowing to increase the execution time of the script. As I cant increase the time limit the script is timing out. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is an ugly hack I remember for server environments where you cannot control the timeout. Here goes -

- when a process like this starts, you set a processid in the db
- you get the timeout for the page and reload the page yourself before the timeout happens using javascript, but on each such load (using javascript), pass the processid stored in the db
- on the page load, you check if the processid exists in the db and accordingly restart the script from
  where it was left (I am not sure how this will work in case of upload/download, but probably you can
  break the file into pieces).
- on completion of the job, delete the processid from the db.

As I mentioned this is an ugly hack, so please only use it if you are left with no other choice or if anyone else cannot suggest a better option. let know how it goes or if you need any details.

Comment: I got this link http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/max-ex.php which may be helpful in my case, but don't know how to use it? Where to put my script? before or after the sleep function.

Comment: @Raul - you can only use that option if not in safe mode.

Comment: @David - I agree it's an ugly hack :-) but i dont see many options on a server which doesn't let you change php settings. I just put it here so people can see this hack and think "oh i can do better and give a better solution" ;-)..

Comment: Don't get me wrong, your hack is wonderful! but I had to say something for sheer envy! :) Wonderful that we have people like you around SO!

Answer (score 0):

Got this from the PHP manual:

> You can not change this setting with
>   ini_set() when running in safe mode.
>   The only workaround is to turn off
>   safe mode or by changing the time
>   limit in the php.ini.

So, I think that you have pretty slim options